# intent in fragment keeps crashing problem with the manifest, android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-manifest

I'm getting the error

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.tulio.appkolev/com.example.tulio.appkolev.fragments.registerFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

After looking online and trying several pages I couldn't find a solution

The basics are, I have this layout to login in an app at the end of the page I have a link to create an account. When clicked, the app crashes and shows me that error

I'm sure the code is not up to standards

main

```
package com.example.tulio.appkolev;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {

private final AppCompatActivity activity = MainActivity.this;

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private InputValidation inputValidation;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState==null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new loginFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.account);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.settings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new settingsFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.account:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new loginFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.assignments:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new assigmentsFragment()).commit();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    private void initObjects(){
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
        inputValidation = new InputValidation(activity);
    }
    }
```

login class

```
package com.example.tulio.appkolev.fragments;


import com.example.tulio.appkolev.R;
import com.example.tulio.appkolev.helper.InputValidation;
import com.example.tulio.appkolev.sql.DatabaseHelper;


public class loginFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final Fragment fragment = loginFragment.this;
    private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
    private TextInputLayout input_email;
    private TextInputLayout input_password;
    private TextInputEditText input_edit_email;
    private TextInputEditText input_edit_password;
    private AppCompatButton button_login;
    private AppCompatTextView registerLink;
    private InputValidation inputValidation;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

      //   initObjects();

        button_login = (AppCompatButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        button_login.setOnClickListener(this);
        registerLink = (AppCompatTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.registerLink);
        registerLink.setOnClickListener(this);
        nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);
        input_email = (TextInputLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        input_password = (TextInputLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.input_password);
        input_edit_email = (TextInputEditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_edit_email);
        input_edit_password = (TextInputEditText) v.findViewById(R.id.input_edit_password);

        button_login = (AppCompatButton) v.findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        registerLink = (AppCompatTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.registerLink);

        button_login.setOnClickListener(this);
        registerLink.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_login:
                verifyFromSQLite();
                break;
            case R.id.registerLink:
                Intent intentRegister = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), registerFragment.class);
                startActivity(intentRegister);
                break;
        }

    }

  /*  private void initObjects(){
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        inputValidation = new InputValidation();
    }*/

        private void verifyFromSQLite(){
            if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(input_edit_email, input_email, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
                return;
            }
            if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextEmail(input_edit_email,  input_email, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
                return;
            }
            if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(input_edit_password,  input_password, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
                return;
            }

            if (databaseHelper.checkUser(input_edit_email.getText().toString().trim()
                    , input_edit_password.getText().toString().trim())) {
                Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), profileFragment.class);
                accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", input_edit_email.getText().toString().trim());
                emptyInputEditText();
                startActivity(accountsIntent);
            } else {
               // Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.error_valid_email_password), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


        private void emptyInputEditText(){
            input_edit_email.setText(null);
            input_edit_password.setText(null);
        }

    }
```

register class

```
package com.example.tulio.appkolev.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.tulio.appkolev.R;

public class registerFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    }

}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tulio.appkolev">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

i would like when clicked to take me to the register layout. please let me know all what can i improve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below line cause the issue.

```
Intent intentRegister = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),registerFragment.class);
startActivity(intentRegister);
```

Intent is used only for activity while you are calling fragment using that intent which obviously give you a crash. So instead of using intent to call fragment you have to use fragment manager for that.

```
  getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new registerFragment())
        .commit();
```

Notes: It's good practice to use camelcase naming standard for any class you are using in project.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intentRegister = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),registerFragment.class);
startActivity(intentRegister);
```

registerFragmentis a Fragment ,not activity.
You can't start it by startActivity.
You can change the registerFragmentis extends activity and declared this activity in AndroidManifest.xml